# How to add custom snippets for neovim to a particular location when using friendly-snippets

Tags: neovim, snippets

I have `friendly-snippets`(https://github.com/rafamadriz/friendly-snippets), which works.

The (python) snippets that it uses are installed at

```
$HOME/.local/share/nvim/site/pack/packer/start/friendly-snippets/snippets/python
```

And they work, but I would like to add some of my own snippets to this.

If I edit some of the files in:

```
> tree python/
python/
├── base.json
├── comprehension.json
├── debug.json
├── python.json
└── unittest.json
```

Then they work, but ideally I would like to have my custom snippets stored in a different location than where the default snippets are.

So my question is - how can I add custom snippets in `$HOME/dotfiles/neovim/nvim` (or whatever), for a particular language (in this case python), to be used with the `friendly-snippets` plugin.

If there's any information missing please let me know and I'll add it

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the package.json file in your friendly snippets directory. In your case, it's `$HOME/.local/share/nvim/site/pack/packer/start/friendly-snippets`
2. Search for your required language.
3. Edit or Create new the path to your required snippets file. for example, you may find

```
{
    "language": "python",
    "path": "./snippets/python/base.json"
},
```

Change the path here. Done.

Comment: @Friedrich is it alright now?

Comment: It's perfect ;-)